# Lazy Modules and bundle size

Tags: angular

I have numerous lazy loaded modules where i import angular material components, given the sizes of these modules i am trying to understand if my logic is right in terms of how these are being bundled.

If i have two modules A and B and i import MatSelectModule does this mean that it will duplicate the size of A and B by MatSelectModule and hence increase the overall size - or is MatSelectModule simply being referenced by these modules in which case this is not an issue? I'm trying to unpack why some of my modules are so big when in essence they are referencing the same modules/libraries across each other.

Comment: [Once in a while a new question pops up on stackoverflow from a developer worried that importing a module...](https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular#module-caching). Give this article a read, it should help clear some misunderstanding regarding angular modules.

Answer (score 2):

Yes importing same module in different modules of your project, will increase size of that module. But the best practice to import third module is, crate a separate module name it like ComponentsModule and import all the third party modules in to this ComponentsModule. After that import that ComponentsModule  module in our App Module. And as our lazy loaded modules are declared inside our App module, these third party components can be assessed in out lazy loaded modules.